# Javascript: onScroll event (using Prototype) doesn't work on IE?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I am trying to trigger the onScroll event this way using prototype:

```
Event.observe(document, 'scroll', function(){
    alert('boo');
});
```

It works perfectly on Firefox, but nothing happens on IE. Does anyone know why? and if there is another way to do so?

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try attaching it to the `window` instead:

```
Event.observe(window, 'scroll', function() {
        alert('boo');
});
```

Works for me on IE, FF. Honestly, I don't know why it would work attaching it to the `document`.

Answer (score 8):

Don't know if anyone is still following this answer, but i thought i would put down some of the information i found. In general the *scroll* event is supported on "**window**" on the following browsers below...

- **IE** 5,6,7,8 (don't know about 9)
- **FF** all versions
- **Safari** 3.0.. up
- **Chrome**
- **Opera** 9.0.. up

However, when it comes to the **document**, it is not supported on any of the IE versions. Now, the funny thing is the **Iphone 3G browser** is the reverse of **IE**. The scroll event only works on the **document**. For more info on this, check out http://www.quirksmode.org. This site has alot of good stuff on event handling. Hope this helps someone...